# Dynamically naming DataFrames imported into Python using portions of original file name

Tags: python, dataframe, naming-conventions, dynamic-programming

**BACKGROUND:** 
I'm importing several dfs from the World Bank, which have names such as "`API_AG.SRF.TOTL.K2_DS2_en_csv_v2_10366083.csv`." I have several of these files with similar naming conventions saved in the same folder on my computer.

**OBJECTIVE:**
In the end I want to import all of these files and assign them names based on the original file names. Specifically, I want to delimit the original name on "." and name each df `"country" + "_" + str(delimitedname[1]) + "_" + str(delimitedname[2])).lower()` (e.g., in the case of "`API_AG.SRF.TOTL.K2_DS2_en_csv_v2_10366083.csv.`" the df would be named "`country_srf_totl.`"

I already have code that creates a list of the names of all of csv files in the folder, delimits the respective names by "." and creates a list of new names for the dfs (see below)

```
grab_files = []
for folders, subfolders, files in os.walk(r'filepath'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            grab_files.append(str(file))

names = []
for i in range(0,len(grab_files)):
    name0 = grab_files[i].split(".")
    names.append(str("country" + "_" + str(name0[1]) + "_" + str(name0[2])).lower())

print(names)
```

This results in the following list:

```
['country_pop_totl_ds2_en_csv_v2_10307762', 'country_gdp_mktp', 'country_gdp_mktp', 'country_srf_totl']
```

**ISSUE:** 
The problem is actually assigning these names during the import portion of my code.

Here's what I was trying initially (Note: "`fp0`" is a defined filepath to the folder containing the csv files):

```
for i in range(0,len(names)):
    eval('names[i]') = pd.read_csv(fp0 + str(grab_files[i]))
```

I know that the issue here is that eval is returning the string associated with 'names[i]' rather than an object that can take on an assigned value. AND I KNOW EVAL IS THE ROOT OF ALL THINGS... EVAL, but it's all I could think to do.

**TL/DR:**
Eventually I'm going to be importing 30+ files with the same naming convention, and I'd like to be able to import them and assign them new names based off of the old names as dynamically as possible.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with dynamic variable names is it's a [Trojan Rabbit](https://youtu.be/tS_JBDRk8o0?t=243). Once you have defined a dynamic variable,

```
name = 'foo'
globals()[name] = 3
```

what can you do with it? If we are working at an interactive prompt, then fine -- we can now use our variable:

```
print(foo)
# 3
```

(But if we were working at an interactive prompt then why couldn't we have just defined `foo` the normal way, e.g. `foo = 3`?)

So, since we are writing code (and not at an interactive prompt) [what happens now](https://youtu.be/tS_JBDRk8o0?t=276)?
We know the new variable has the same name as the value of the string `name`.
But we don't know the value of `name`. We only have `name`.

So even after defining the global variable with `globals()[name] = 3`, we're still forced to refer to it via `name`:

```
print(globals()[name])
```

Well, that just... sucks.

We might as well use a `dict` instead of `globals()` so we don't pollute the global namespace:

```
dfs = dict()
for name, grab_file in zip(names, grab_files):
    dfs[name] = pd.read_csv(fp0 + str(grab_file))
```

and now we can refer to the DataFrame using `dfs[name]`.